# Problem with accessing the api in a web page hosted in the IIS

Tags: autodesk-forge

I am making a forge web application, I have this page on an IIS server and it does not work for me, it does not display the model and it generates the following error in the front:

onDocumentLoadFailure() - errorCode:7

ForgeViewer.js

when I run my application locally and it generates a port if it works correctly.

Could you help me since I think the error is that you can access the api or something from a port that forge uses for the IIS

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Error code 7 stands for:

> An unhandled response code was returned when accessing a network resource (HTTP 'everything else')

This error is issued by the viewer when its requests fail with response code other than 401, 403, 404, or 5XX.

I'd suggest that you check the Network tab of your browser's dev tools. For example, here's how to do that in [Google Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/). The failing request (typically highlighted in red) can typically provide more information about why it failed.